# Android DatePicker Disable all dates

Tags: java, android

I want to disable all the dates in my DatePicker because it's date is already set and it shouldn't be changed. I saw how to change the dates before a particular date even after a particular date but I don't know how to disable all the dates. Any ideas?

Comment: You can not disable dates in Native `DatePicker`. What you can do is set the Max/Min Date See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759664/set-mindate-and-maxdate-in-datepicker). The dates out of bound will not show up . If you want to disable some particular date you need to use a Custom `DatePicker`.